How to distinguish different configurations between Mac and Windows using the settings sync function that comes with vscode?
After switching from the settings sync plugin to the built-in synchronization function,
I found that when using the synchronization function on Windows and macos, they will cover the other party and cannot be independent of each other.
Is this function not provided, or is there a configuration problem?
It is hoped that settings sync can be used to identify and load different configurations according to the system.
